# how to assign an sql value to this python variable

Tags: python, database, sqlite

ok i got this as simple as i can, everythings working and i need one last thing before I'm done with this issue
i am using sqlite3 module in python
i also have very limited sql expierance

the problem-
i need to take the only value out of an sql table; the tablename is saves and the row id is 0 the name of the row is lvl. i need to then assign this as the value of the python variable lvl. Then on closure of the program i need to update the sql table with the current value of the python variable lvl (it will take the place of the data i just retrieved--there will also be numerous operations in between).

My code for assigning the value of the python Variable

```
conn = sql.connect('databaserm/database')
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('SELECT 0 FROM saves')
lvl = curs.fetchone()
conn.commit
conn.close()
```

after running this i get the output
    None

and my code for adding data to the database on closure

```
            elif choice == q:
                if choice == q:
                    cn = sqlite3.connect('/databaserm/database')
                    curs = cn.cursor()
                    curs.execute('INSERT INTO saves (lvl) VALUES (?)', lvl)        
                    cn.commit
                    cn.close()
                loop1 = 0
                loop = 10000
                print "Goodbye!"
                sys.exit(0)
```

after running this with a preloaded database and the previous code ommited i get a connection error

i would be overjoyed at any help i'm offered and hope to work out a solution to this soon

Comment: why was this scored down, if there was anything important that i left out i would be more than happy to edit it into my question?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT 0 FROM saves` is not sensible (or valid) SQL, you probably want to do something like `SELECT * FROM saves WHERE lvl = 0`

I suggest reading some [sql tutorial](http://www.google.fi/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=en&xhr=t&q=sql+tutorial&cp=7&pq=sqlite%20tutorial&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=sql+tut&pbx=1&fp=cfde86c64acd8306&ion=1)

Comment: ...thats actually what i had before reading some sql tutorial *facepalm* no disrespect--edit-- i just tried you suggestion and got the same results